# How to insert data from text to mysql?

Tags: ssh, mysql, scripts

I get this text from router via ssh. But I want to insert user(fr-XXX) and macadress(F0:24:75:33:22:11) to mysql routerusers table.

```
Flags: M - mac-cookie 
 #   USER             DOMAIN             MAC-ADDRESS       EXPIRES-IN          
 0 M fr-65111111                        F0:24:75:33:22:11 4d23h56m17s         
 1 M fr-x0584444                        50:32:75:33:22:11 4d19h8m43s          
 2 M fr-AA055555                        3C:AB:8E:33:22:11 4d22h17m28s         
 3 M fr-1126666                         90:B6:86:33:22:11 4d19h57m31s           
 ....
 ....
 ....
 ....
```

I think first encode this file to json than insert until users finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed` filter to convert your text table into json objects:

```
cat your_text_file | \
sed -e "s/.*\(fr-\w*\)\s*\([0-9A-F:]*\).*/{"user":\"\1\",\"mac\":\"\2\"},/g"
```

You will get objects like this:

```
{user:"fr-65111111","mac":"F0:24:75:33:22:11"},
{user:"fr-x0584444","mac":"50:32:75:33:22:11"},
{user:"fr-AA055555","mac":"3C:AB:8E:33:22:11"},
{user:"fr-1126666","mac":"90:B6:86:33:22:11"},
```

Which you can then process further to insert into database or you can directly update the `sed` command to generate you sql insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to convert the records into SQL queries and to import the SQL queries into the database (as you would with an SQL dump) all at once.

This `awk` command just converts the records into SQL queries:

```
awk '/ [0-9]+/ {print "INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES (\""$3"\", \""$4"\");"}' inputfile
```

```
user@debian:~$ awk '/ [0-9]+/ {print "INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES (\""$3"\", \""$4"\");"}' inputfile
INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES ("fr-65111111", "F0:24:75:33:22:11");
INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES ("fr-x0584444", "50:32:75:33:22:11");
INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES ("fr-AA055555", "3C:AB:8E:33:22:11");
INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES ("fr-1126666", "90:B6:86:33:22:11");
```

Using a process substitution you can directly import the output of the command into the database using this command:

```
mysql -u root -p foo < <(awk '/ [0-9]+/ {print "INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES (\""$3"\", \""$4"\");"}' inputfile)
```

```
user@debian:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 61
Server version: 5.5.44-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE foo
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE bar (
    -> id INT(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> field1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    -> field2 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
    -> )
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM bar
    -> ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
user@debian:~$ mysql -u root -p foo < <(awk '/ [0-9]+/ {print "INSERT INTO bar (field1, field2) VALUES (\""$3"\", \""$4"\");"}' inputfile)
Enter password: 
user@debian:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 69
Server version: 5.5.44-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> USE foo
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> SELECT * FROM bar
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------------------+
| id | field1      | field2            |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
|  1 | fr-65111111 | F0:24:75:33:22:11 |
|  2 | fr-x0584444 | 50:32:75:33:22:11 |
|  3 | fr-AA055555 | 3C:AB:8E:33:22:11 |
|  4 | fr-1126666  | 90:B6:86:33:22:11 |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```